# Nested polymorphism in C++ using virtual fucntions

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
 public:
 virtual void print(){
  std::cout << "base\n";
 }
};

class dr : public base {
 public:
 void print(){
  std::cout << "dr\n";
 }
};


class last : public dr {
 public:
 void print(){
  std::cout << "last\n";
 }
};

int main(){
 dr *d = new last();
 d->print();
 return 0;
}
```

In the above code, only the `base` class includes a virtual function.
`dr` and `last` do not include a virtual function and yet polymorphism is still working.
The output of this code is `last`. (It should have been `dr` without polymorphism kicking in).

Does this mean polymorphism works as long as some base class has a virtual function, even though non of the derived classes have one?

Comment: *dr and last do not include a virtual function* -- Yes they do.

Comment: Yes Dan, Runtime polymorphism will be applicable if derived class is having a base class with virtual function. Virtual table will be created for all the derived class.

Comment: If you like to document-in-code that a derived class method is a virtual method being overridden from a base class, you can use `void print() override` where the `override` specifier both ensures that a virtual base class method actually exists, and documents that you intend to override it.

Answer (score 2):

Both `dr::print` and `last::print` override `base::print`, they're [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) too; the keyword `virtual` is optional here.

(emphasis mine)

> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (**whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration**) and overrides Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).

Comment: does this logic also work for "pure virtual"? where `print() = 0` is used?

Comment: so derived classed that actually define "print" would also be "pure virtual" or just "virtual"?

Comment: @Dan Just virtual. Pure virtual functions are declared with `= 0` and have no definition.

Comment: @Dan Oh, I got what you meant. It doesn't work for *pure virtual*. If you want the function in derived class be *pure virtual* you have to write `= 0` explicitly.